# Spring @RedisHash findAll() return null values

Tags: java, spring, redis

I'm using Redis to store students with entity:

```
@RedisHash("Student")
public class Student implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Indexed
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
    // getters
    // setters
    // Constructor with full parameters
}
```

and repository:

```
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<Student, Long> {
}
```

I can save a list of students to Redis database and get that list without any error:

```
@Autowired
StudentRepository repo;

List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
Student student1 = new Student(........);
students.add(student1);
Student student2 = new Student(........);
students.add(student2);
repo.findAll().forEach(){
    System.out.println(student);
}
```

The problem is when other project of mine (I'm building apps with micro-service architecture), I use `findAll()` function to get that list of students, it returns a list of two `null` elements. If I use `findByName(String name)`, it still returns desired result.

Anyone who used to face this problem can help me, thank you in advanced ?

Comment: What do you mean by 2 `null` elements, does it return 2 objects with their fields being null? Do you get a NPE?

Comment: it returns a list of 2 objects, and both 2 objects are `null`, not their fields being `null`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out my `Student` class on the other project has the same `@RedisHash("Student")` but different full class name (same class name but different package). I think this issue belongs to the library.

**Updated**: cause `@RedisHash` doesn't work like expected, I found the way: that is adding `@TypeAlias("Student")` to the entity `Student`, therefore you can place `Student` anywhere in your source code

Comment: I tried this, @TypeAlias("Student") but it still returning [null, null].

Comment: UPDATE: I need to remove and push data again, after that I get the data. @TypeAlias worked!!